# Saving a query in a variable then adding a where clause?

Tags: mysql, variables, subquery

I have a bit of a problem with this query. It works great, but I'm a fan of DRY and this looks like it could easily be improved:

```
SELECT
    users.*,
    (
        SELECT user_information.value
        FROM users
        LEFT JOIN user_information
        ON user_information.userid = users.id
        WHERE user_information.name = 'account_name'
    ),
    (
        SELECT user_information.value
        FROM users
        LEFT JOIN user_information
        ON user_information.userid = users.id
        WHERE user_information.name = 'account_code'
    ),
    (
        SELECT user_information.value
        FROM users
        LEFT JOIN user_information
        ON user_information.userid = users.id
        WHERE user_information.name = 'account_id'
    ),
WHERE ...
```

The part:

```
SELECT user_information.value
FROM users
LEFT JOIN user_information
ON user_information.userid = users.id
```

Is exactly the same in each subquery (there will be about 10 sub queries in future) but the where clause changes each time. Would it be possible to save that in a variable, and then use it while appending that different where clause it each one in mysql?

Answer (score 1):

You can join the `user_information` table to your query and group the results:

```
SELECT   users.*,
         GROUP_CONCAT(IF(i.name = 'account_name', i.value, NULL)),
         GROUP_CONCAT(IF(i.name = 'account_code', i.value, NULL)),
         GROUP_CONCAT(IF(i.name = 'account_id'  , i.value, NULL))
FROM     users LEFT JOIN user_information AS i ON i.userid = users.id
WHERE    ...
GROUP BY users.id
```